# How can I access the desktop pixels in order to build a Translucent Material view of it?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui, blur

First of all I have to say this question is not making a blur or translucent function or algorithm, in this question I will use apple build in API for making an Image translucent, as you know any translucent function need pixels to start processing the blur function, this question try to gather the needed material or pixels for this process.

The reason this question exist is because the apple API in macOS-SwiftUI(Material) or macOS-Cocoa(NSVisualEffectView) doest not let us to custom the blur radius in translucenting the macOS desktop behind this views, and we have very limited options to chose.

There for I decided to access the pixels in desktop for making them blurly in the radius I wish.

Here is my try for this goal and the issues:

1 - The app fills very slow and not smooth enough to make use of it.

2 - I cannot get the pixel where app located in desktop, because the app window itself covering that area pixels, I have to find a way to omit the app window in process of making needed image for blur function, therefor right now I am reading the left side of app for ignoring this issue.

If you look to this code or run it, you may think it is not the right way, and I am agree with you that is why I made this question, but do not forget in theory what I am doing is correct, more info: NSVisualEffectView or Material both they need to access the pixels behind them to start their work, since those not giving the customisation I am looking for, I am trying to access the pixels myself and using Apple API for making blur with the custom radius.

Here is my codes:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

var window: NSWindow = NSWindow()

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        window.styleMask = [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .fullSizeContentView]
        window.backingType = .buffered
        window.delegate = sharedDelegate
        window.title = "Window"
        window.isOpaque = false

        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())
        
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
    }

}

class MyNSWindowDelegate: NSObject, NSWindowDelegate {
    
    func windowWillMove(_ notification: Notification) {
        postMyNotification(value: notification)
    }
    
    func windowDidMove(_ notification: Notification) {
        postMyNotification(value: notification)
    }
}

let sharedDelegate: MyNSWindowDelegate = MyNSWindowDelegate()

let myNotificationName: Notification.Name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "myNotificationName")

func postMyNotification(value: Notification) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: myNotificationName, object: value))
}


let nsApplication: NSApplication = NSApplication.shared
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = AppDelegate()
nsApplication.delegate = appDelegate
nsApplication.run()
```

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var cgImage: CGImage? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Color.gray.overlay(content: {
            
            if let unwrappedImage: CGImage = cgImage {
                
                Image(decorative: unwrappedImage, scale: 1.0)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .blur(radius: 2, opaque: false)
                
            }
            
        })
        .animation(.default, value: cgImage)
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: myNotificationName)) { newNotification in
            
            if let unwrappedNewNotification = newNotification.object as? Notification {
                
                if let unwrappedNSWindow = unwrappedNewNotification.object as? NSWindow {

                    cgImage =  pixelColorReader(point: unwrappedNSWindow.frame.origin, size: unwrappedNSWindow.frame.size)
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

func pixelColorReader(point: CGPoint, size: CGSize) -> CGImage {
    
    let y = NSScreen.main!.frame.height - (point.y + size.height - 28/2.0)
    
    let screenID = NSScreen.main!.deviceDescription[NSDeviceDescriptionKey("NSScreenNumber")] as! UInt32
    let image: CGImage = CGDisplayCreateImage(CGDirectDisplayID(screenID), rect: CGRect(x: point.x - size.width, y: y, width: size.width, height: size.height))!
    return image
    
}
```

Comment: could you play around with opacity of the translucent view? There are different materials (thin, ultra thin, thick etc), See if applying opacity to one of the materials helps you achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, that would be not be decent as working on radius but thanks.